# Proving that if $T\in\operatorname{Hom}[V,W]$ has null space $X\cap Y$, then $T[X+Y]=T[X]\oplus T[Y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Here's my progress:

If $X$ and $Y$ are subspaces of a finite-dimensional vector-space, then

$d(X+Y)+d(X∩Y)=d(X)+d(Y)$

, where $d(A)$ is the dimension of $A$.
Then,

$d(X∩Y)=d(X)+d(Y)-d(X+Y)$.

But $X∩Y$ is also the null space of $T∈\operatorname{Hom}[V,W]$, so if $T$ has null space $N⊂V$ and range $R⊂W$, then $R$ is finite-dimensional and

$d(V)=d(N)+d(R)$.

$R$ is a subset of $W$, and any independent finite subset of a finite-dimensional space can be extended to a basis; and if $W$ is finite-dimensional, all bases of $W$ contain the same number of elements; therefore

$d(R)=d(W)$.

So now we have

$d(V)=d(N)+d(W)$,

and since

$d(N)=d(X∩Y)$, we can write:

$d(V)=d(X)+d(Y)-d(X+Y)+d(W)$

and

$d(X)+d(Y)-d(X+Y)=d(V)-d(W)$

If I assume that $T$ is an isomorphism,$d(V)-d(W)=0$, then the problem is solved, because in this case, i could write:

$d(X+Y)=d(X)+d(Y)$

And therefore;

$(X+Y)=X⊕Y$

,and, because of the bijectivity of $T$,

$T[X+Y]=T[X]+T[Y]$.

The problem is that I don't know any argument I could use to support the fact that T is an isomorphism. Is my proof wrong so far?

Comment: I'm sorry to disregard what you've written, but: I think the finite dimensionality is a red herring. It shouldn't be necessary to use dimensions at all.

Comment: I thought it was necessary because this exercise is in a chapter about dimensions

Comment: Well, let's try it your way. I don't think you can say that $R$ and $W$ have the same dimension. Unless you make some reduction there's no reason for that to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Dimensions is a red herring, as commented. It's a matter of understanding how nullspaces affect injectivity.

The claim is just the claim that $T(X)\cap T(Y)=0$. Say $T(x)=T(y)$ for $x\in X,y\in Y$. Then $T(x-y)=0$ so $x-y\in\ker T=X\cap Y$ so $y\in X$ follows, so $y\in Y\cap X$ so $T(y)=0$ and $T(x)=0$ also. Thus $T(X)\cap T(Y)=0$ and $T(X+Y)=T(X)\oplus T(Y)$ as an internal direct sum.